# How to get polygon's point after drawin a polygon using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, polygon, openlayers-3, interaction

Using OpenLayers 3.

Here is my current code on the drawend even of drawing a polygon interaction:

```
myInteraction.on('drawend', function (e) {
  var c = e.target.coordinates ;
});
```

I want to get my polygon's coordinates in variable c but I cannot find the right syntax, I have already tried:

```
  var c = e.target.getCoordinates(); //This is how I do for a LineString
  var c = e.target.getVertices();
  var c = e.target.geometry...;
  var c = e.target.getGeometry();
...
```

But they're all undefined.

Comment: Hm no. If you read the questions, they are different and if you read the answers, they are dfferent too.

Comment: Actually, I have it. But thanks because this made me notice that the last coordinate is identical to the first one and I don't need this repetition in my further algorithms.

Comment: You can reference in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122250/how-to-get-the-feature-location-in-openlayers-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this works

```
e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```